# oracle adf mobile jsonObject["coords"] not found

Tags: jdeveloper, oracle-maf

I am getting error while using start Location Monitor,The error is observed in Android 5.
I am getting the following error:jsonObject["coords"] not found.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found the solution . . .
**update adf mobile framework**
or using javascript code to get Location 
as the following:
in backing bean  call the Javascript method using :

```
 AdfmfContainerUtilities.invokeContainerJavaScriptFunction(AdfmfJavaUtilities.getFeatureName(),"getLocation", new Object[] { });
```

And in maf-feature.xml include Javascript file having content as mentioned :

```
    function getLocation() {
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
    var timeoutVal = 10 * 1000 * 1000;
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition, displayError,
    { enableHighAccuracy: true, timeout: timeoutVal, maximumAge: 0 });
    }
    else {
        alert("error in finding location");


    }
}


function showPosition(position) {
alert( position.coords.longitude+" "+ position.coords.latitude);


adf.mf.el.setValue( {
            "name" : "#{pageFlowScope.longitude}", "value" : position.coords.longitude
        },
        onSuccess, onFail);

        adf.mf.el.setValue( {
            "name" : "#{pageFlowScope.latitude}", "value" : position.coords.latitude
        },
        onSuccess, onFail);   
}


function onSuccess(request, response) {
    alert(response);
}


function onFail(request, response) {
    alert(response);
}


function displayError(error) {
  var errors = {
    1: 'Permission denied',
    2: 'Position unavailable',
    3: 'Request timeout'
  };
  alert("Error: " + errors[error.code]);
}
```